# Verifying user input is integer or empty with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I need to make sure user input entered in textbox with pysimplegui is integer or empty. For this I am following below method:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('SandyBeach')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter your Phone')],

    [sg.Text('Phone', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key="lp1")],
    [sg.Button("e"), sg.Quit()]
]
window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "e":
        height = int(values['lp1'])
        print(type(height))


        if height == "" or type(height) == int:
            print("s")
        else:
            print("n")

    if event in [sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Quit"]:
        break


window.close()
```

The issue here is if I make `height = int(values['lp1'])`   & leave the input blank I get ValueError:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '223d'

if I make `height = height = values['lp1']` height type is str

also the expected output should be n when string is entered.
Kindly suggest how to rectify it.

Answer (score 4):

You will get an exception if you call `int` with argument which is not an integer-format string.

Example code as following

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('SandyBeach')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter your Phone')],
    [sg.Text('Phone', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key="lp1")],
    [sg.Button("e"), sg.Quit()]
]
window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Quit"):
        break
    elif event == "e":
        text = values['lp1']
        if text == '':
            print('Null string')
        else:
            try:
                value = int(text)
                print(f'Integer: {value}')
            except:
                print("Not Integer")

window.close()
```