# How do you displayed output as currency in Python?( Using PySimpleGUI)?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

New to python and have little to no experience in coding but learning. I am looking to display currency when a user fills out a field in a forum. Would like the field to be limited to numbers as well so the user does not mistakenly enters text. Where/how would I write those string? I am use PySimpleGUI. Also is PySimpleGUI the best for this? Would I need to use other scripts?

```
This is what i am using to pratice:
```

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a little color to your windows
# All the stuff inside your window. This is the PSG magic code compactor...
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],*<----to display currency when user types in numerical characters examples: $1,000.00/$20.00 or $1,000/$20
            [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events"
while True:             
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: I suggest putting a label near it containing the currency symbol.

Comment: For the integer part look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431332/verifying-user-input-is-integer-or-empty-with-pysimplegui